# php application asking intl but already installed

Tags: apt, php, webserver

My (Symfony) application currently crashes, throwing the error:

> ("The Symfony\Component\Intl\Collator\Collator::__construct() method's argument $locale value 'fr' behavior is not implemented. Only the locale "en" is supported.  Please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities.")

I actually didn't have `intl` installed, so I did

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

That also got `libicu52` dependency in the process
My application still complains with the same error
I restarted my web server (NginX with php-fpm) manually (even if apt-get does it already).

How can I find the origin of the issue ?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723804/a-php-platform-install-ask-me-intl-extension-but-it-seems-already-installed) help? There is a line in app/config/config.yml to be changed.

Comment: The question is pretty much the same but a default installation already contains the `default_locale` parameter set in `app/config/config.yml`

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY did you found a fix for this? I'm having the exact same problem. (thank you)

Comment: Well nope, thx for the vote up

Answer (score 0):

try this if original solution does not work for you:
By default, symfony2 is able to manage the "en" extension but to get other language, you have to install the php-intl extension.

The easiest option is to install it with the composer, because it expose global variable for you ... etc

All of this is explained here symfony/components/intl.

For the composer extension installation it's symfony/components/using_components.

So after eading this, you need to execute :

```
composer require symfony/intl
```

DO NOT FORGET TO RESTART YOUR APACHE2 SERVER (sudo service apache2 restart)

source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723804/a-php-platform-install-ask-me-intl-extension-but-it-seems-already-installed